# In R Shiny, How to create matrix /table enabling the viewer to sort from both column name and row name

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

In R Shiny, I'm creating a matrix and I want to enable the viewer to sort either from the sorting arrows "besides column name" or by the row names, as shown in the attached photo:

[image]

Comment: In your server function, you can use `renderDataTable` and then `dataTableOutput` in your UI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I'm a beginner, can you help me with the detailed code?

Comment: As mentioned by @bjorn2bewild, you can make use of the `DT` library's datatable, renderDataTable& dataTableOutput for your task. Refer the documentation of DT [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/). For an example in Shiny, have a look at the Shiny gallery sample [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html).

Comment: If you edit your question to include the code you have so far I can provide some input (you will always be more likely to get a response if you post a minimum working example (MWE) of your code with your question).

Comment: @Argon none of the examples is the same as I want, the row headers don't contain sorting arrows (descending or ascending)